# Value assigning from text file variables

Tags: java, data-structures

Got a problem and I don't know how to approach this one.

From the text file I get a line like this: "x = 45 + 3". (Variables are only single lowercase/uppercase letters). Output should be 48, like normal calculation.

Now I need to calculate that equation and use the 'x' in another equation like 
"y = x + 15 - 7".

So far I've come up an idea to use substring to get the calculation part, i.e '45+3'. But I can't think any good idea how to keep variable and use it in another equation since next equation is a string form a text file also.

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: Every line in the text file will have = sign?

Comment: No, its like a programming language kind of thing, where you will need to calculate processes. 
File has lines like these:
"x = 5 + 11"; "y = x - 4"; "print y". One string on a single line.
And output should be 12

Comment: did you get it? do you still need help?

Comment: Not quite. I'm trying to find a way how to get that x from equation and save it, then use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **replace all** x with 45 do the technique of arithmetic you had done before for 45+3

Hope my help works.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    engine.eval("x = 45 + 3");
    engine.eval("y = x + 15 - 7");
    double y = (Double)engine.get("y");
    System.out.println(y);
```

Comment: You can also use `engine.eval("print(y)");` if you don't want to use calculation result in java.

Comment: I'm guessing the original problem is a class assignment -- in which case, this solution may not be properly appreciated...

Comment: yes it is. Im not asking for solution, asking for ideas.